# Combinatorics problem - selecting teams of two from two different groups

Tags: combinatorics

There are 8 boys and 10 girls needed to form 5 boy-girl teams (2 people per team). How many different teams are possible?

My understanding is that $${\binom {8} 5}\times \binom {10} 5$$

would be the number of ways to select a group of ten people (5 boys and 5 girls). But to actually seperate into 5 teams of two, boy and girl in each, we would need to select each team

First team: $8\times 10$ choices,

Second team: $7 \times 9$ choices,

...

Fifth team: $4 \times 6 $ choices

Then finally, divide through by the number of permutations of 5 teams so

The answer should be:

$$
\frac{(8\times 10) \cdot (7\times 9) \cdot (6\times 8) \cdot (5\times 7) \cdot (4\times 6) }{5!} = \frac{^{10}P_5\cdot {^8}P_5}{5!}=1,693, 440
$$

Is this correct or is my logic flawed somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, and your answer is correct. You could also have argued as follows, starting with your first observation. There are, as you say, $\binom85\binom{10}5$ ways to choose $5$ boys and $5$ girls. Now line up the boys. There are $5$ ways to pick a teammate for the first boy in line, $4$ ways to pick a teammate for the second boy in line, and so on, so there are $5!$ ways to match up the boys and the girls. That gives you a total of $\binom85\binom{10}55!=1\,693\,440$ different ways to form $5$ teams, each consisting of a boy and a girl.

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: @b.b.89: My pleasure!